# TFS Work item cration - Default Iteration

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have problem to discover workaround to set default iteration for workitems what are created from Team Foundation Server 2015 Dashboard widget (on picture).

[image]

I have iterations (pic. 2) and my expectation is like this.: When Stakeholder come to web and create new work item. This work item should have iteration 'rectangle' (because this iteration is set in administration as default), but current behavior is that have iteration 'August' because this iteration is current.
When i create work item from Work tab the behavior is correct and work item have iteration 'rectangle' and is ready to be ordered by user with license  <> 'Stakeholder'.

How can I achieve my expectations ?

Thanks for help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

Iterations have own id. And is possible to show them in column options in Backlog tab.
When we have iteration id number we can include it in new work item template link:

```
http|https://<template-link>&%5BSystem.IterationId%5D=<iteration-id>
```

To generate template link use link in circle (visible only when work item is not already saved)

[image]

Reference links helped me:

[Use work item templates to pre-populate fields](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/productivity/work-item-template)

[Areas and iterations field reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997576.aspx)

[Customize area and iteration paths](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/modify-areas-iterations)

Comment: I didn't think you could update that work item creation dashboard widget. My team looked into using that but we were unable to find a way to add fields to that widget. I used templates and a program called teamlook that integrated into outlook which i used to publish multiple work requests sent to our inbox into work items the team could pull into their individual ques and work

Comment: I do not want to change widget to ad columns. Problem is that widget create item and set iteration to current instead of root. But templates solves my problem. I added markdown widget to dashboard with link targeting template.

Comment: Can yo give me any reference to read something about outlook integration or say me how this work item publishing work ?

Comment: Here is the program that we used.Depending on the size of your collection it can be kind of slow but it gets the job done. I have looked into multiple ways to add work items into tfs. I've personally done it through exporting a query to excel, I've converted an excel document into multiple work items using a powershell script. I also was going to write a powershell script to take emails and convert them into work items prior to finding teamlook.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/af686879-cc66-4dfe-bf6a-ba58254bce74